# How to search for mulitple words then count them. Made code for only one word

Tags: java

i have this code that i made and i`m having a problem with the program.

This program is a Word counter with a interface that i created.
It counts how many times i wrote in test.txt word "Vlad Enache" *(my name) . The problem is i don't know how can i make this to search for multiple words , let`s say Vlad Enache, and word dog and cat. And i wanna know how can i define these words from user input in another frame with fields.

Thanks:)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;


public class Andreea {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;
private JButton btnNewButton;
private JLabel lblNewLabel;
private JTextArea txtrVlad;
private JMenuBar menuBar_2;
private JMenu menu;
private JMenuItem menuItem;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Andreea window = new Andreea();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Read from file
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public int ReadFromFile() throws IOException{       

    BufferedReader br;
    Scanner ob;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/test.txt"));      
    ob = new Scanner("PULA");
    String str=ob.next();
     String str1="",str2="";
     int count=0;
     while((str1=br.readLine())!=null)
     {
     str2 +=str1;



    }  

     int index = str2.indexOf(str);

     while (index != -1) {
     count++;
     str2 = str2.substring(index + 1);
     index = str2.indexOf(str);
    }
     return count;
}


/**
 * Create the application.
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public Andreea() throws IOException {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 * @throws IOException 
 */
private void initialize() throws IOException {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 497, 399);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    textField.setForeground(new Color(0, 204, 204));
    textField.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    textField.setEditable(false);
    textField.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 20));
    textField.setBounds(129, 190, 223, 45);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);





    JButton btnCount = new JButton("Count");
    btnCount.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 10));
    btnCount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int count=0;
            try {
                count = ReadFromFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String str="";
            str += count;
            textField.setText(str + " Times" );

        }
    });
    btnCount.setBounds(60, 270, 130, 45);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnCount);

    btnNewButton = new JButton("Reseteaza Counter");
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 10));
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField.setText(null);
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(293, 267, 130, 45);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/...."));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 480, 179);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    txtrVlad = new JTextArea();
    txtrVlad.setText("\u00A9 2014 Vlad Enache (4594)");
    txtrVlad.setBounds(310, 338, 204, 22);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtrVlad);

    menuBar_2 = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar_2);

    menu = new JMenu("New menu");
    menuBar_2.add(menu);

    menuItem = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    menu.add(menuItem);

}
```

}

Comment: Well, thanks for adding code, but don't add in so much. For sure the import statements can go, and anything else that isn't directly related to the problem.

Comment: ok, i`m not having problems sharing this.  i`l keep in mind next time

Comment: Not related to the problem, but don't use String concatenation for reading a file, use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution. Note that this code assume one token per line. You can go back to `String.indexOf` if it is not the case.

```
public int[] ReadFromFile(final String[] tokens) throws IOException
{

    final int[] counters = new int[tokens.length];
    BufferedReader br;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/test.txt"));
    String str1 = "";

    while ((str1 = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
            if (str1.contains(tokens[i]))//if the line contains the token
                counters[i]++;// increase counter for the index of the token

    }

    return counters;
}

...


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{
    //final String[] tokens = new String[] { "Vlad Enache", "dog", "cat" };
    final String[] tokens = textField.getText().split(", ");//get token directly from JTextfield.
   // Would make more sense to use a different JtextField for input and output. 
   //This is just an example
    try
    {
        int[] count;
        count = ReadFromFile(tokens);

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();//storing the result in a stringbuilder

        /* to display the utterance of each token 
        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)
            sb.append(tokens[i] + " is repeated " + count[i] + " times\n");

        textField.setText(sb.toString());//displaying result
        */

        //to sum up all count value
        int sum = 0;
        for(int c : count)
           sum+=c;
        textField.setText(sum+" times");



    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Works like a charm +1, but i have one more question, how can i make it to display only 1 answer to count all together.. like if i have Vlad Enache 1, dog, and cat, to display number 3

Comment: Another Question, Is there any chance to set the   final String[] tokens (word1, word2, word3) from a jtexfield, user input? i`m newbie in java but i try hard

Comment: `JTextField.getText().split(", ");` will return an array of `String`. Be sure to use a `, ` as separator.

Comment: don`t know where to add JTextField.getText().split(", "); could u be more specific? please;)

Comment: For example, assuming you are using `textField` as your input `JTextfield`, use `final String[] tokens = textField.getText().split(", ");` in the method `actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)`

Comment: I mean i want to make a settings form where i can add the strings so i can modify them anytime withouth needing the sourcecode

Comment: Yeah, thats what using a JTextField will do. You will be able to dynamically change the `tokens` without changing the source code. I edited the answer with this point.

Comment: i mean i have the class with jframe and jtextfield named Settings, i can acces it from first main frame throught Menu( file > Settings ) and there i wanna have one jtextfield or more jtextfields where i can add the words for main program to search, then i click save and the program can count using thoes inputs from settings area

Comment: This is really a different question so you should post a new one. But you would have to open a new `Jframe` (that will contain the JTextField) in the `actionPerformed` method of `menuItem.addActionListener` you already start writing in your code.

Comment: @sturcotte06 I said that in the first line of my answer.

Comment: so i got the main class with ur code included, and a second class named Settings that includes only a frame with a jtexfield. if i run the program and open the setting frame i type my name and then press Count it counts first time the Numbers of Lines i get in Text.txt and if i press the count button again it shows 0 times

Comment: To hard to tell without the code. Close this question and open a new one with the code you wrote. I will have a look.

Comment: [link]http://postimg.org/image/ulaxphfc3/
this is my second class. i wanna make thoes 5 jtextAreas to be the strings. and have a button that will perform an Saving for thoes jtextAreas

Comment: As I said, I cant work it out without the source code. A screenshot is not enough. You will have to create a new question and post the code.

Answer (score 0):

final String[] tokens = textField.getText().split(", ");

i got this that get`s token directly from JTextfield.

let`s say i got textField_1 in another form that it is in another class. how to use final String[] tokens = textField_1.getText().split(", ");??????

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't an answer! Judging by ortis's comment yesterday, you need to ask a new question instead.